# PHP loop arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm building a very basic questionnaire (with response page) and it works but my form takes up too much space and looks clunky. How would i loop these question arrays so i can save space?

Here is a small bit of my code asking 2 questions:

```
<h3>Organisation?</h3>
<p><b>It was well organised</b><p>
<?php

    $answers = array("Disagree","Agree");
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
        print '<input type="radio" name="org" value="'.$answers[$i].'">'.$answers[$i];
    };
?>
</p>
<p><b>Adequate materials?</b><p>
<?php

    $answers = array("Disagree","Agree");
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
        print '<input type="radio" name="lib" value="'.$answers[$i].'">'.$answers[$i];
    };
?>
</p>
```

Comment: You can just write everything on 1 line, but i don't think anyone would read that then! (For how many lines are you looking for?)

Comment: I'm looking to merge both questions together if that's possible?

Comment: A [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop would make it better looking.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the two rows in one php tag and use foreach instead, also you should let your php print the headers.

```
<?php
    $answers= array("Disagree","Agree");

    echo "<p><b>It was well organised</b></p><p>";
    foreach ($answers as $value) {
        print '<input type="radio" name="org" value="'.$value.'"> '.$value;
    };
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p><b>Adequate materials?</b></p><p>";
    foreach ($answers as $value) {
        print '<input type="radio" name="lib" value="'.$value.'"> '.$value;
    };
    echo "</p>";

?>
```

Sidenote: You have 4 opening p tags `<p>` and just 2 closing tags `</p>` in your own code. I added another two closing tags in my code where I expected them to be.

Comment: You forgot `<p></p>` around the inputs

Comment: Just to edit the question and remove the tags doesn't makes your answer better!

Comment: @Rizier123 Added the `<p>` and `</p>` tags around the input. I didn't edit the question to make my answer better, but because I was confused about the amount of opening and closing p tags. I put that as a sidenote in my answer.

Comment: @Charlie & Rizier123 Thanks for your responses. Now i'm considering both your answers but which one is better 'practically'? i.e. most complex?

Comment: @user666 To be fair, Riezer123's one has two variables, which he updates in one loop, while I'm using two loops. My code would thus take twice the time. If you're just using "Disagree"/"Agree" you wouldn't see this, but if you were going to be using arrays over 100 strings, you might. I corrected your mistake about the opening and closing tags, which Rizier123 didn't, thus making an invalid code. You could merge our answers and vote them both up, without actually accepting one. It's your choice

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for the notive, can you tell me where i missed to close tags? So i can edit it. (BTW: In your answer the `;` at the end of the foreach aren't necessary )

Comment: @Rizier123 Acutally, now I'm re-reading, you're missing two opening tags. You have `<p>` before the title, `</p>` after the title and `</p>` after the input. You should add another `<p>` before or after the title. I used it after, as `<p><p>` looks ugly, IMHO. PS: Editing your answer just to be accepted and get some reputation would be kinda childish...

Comment: @Charlie & Rizier123 I would vote both you up but i'm not lvl 15 yet lol. Thanks to you both

Comment: @user666 You're welcome. Be sure to ask more questions or give more answers if you want to "level up" aka: get more reputation.

Comment: @Rizier123 Again, user666 can't double-tag you, and I'm first, so I'll novice you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make it a function?

```
function answers($name, $array)
{
    $returnStr="";
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
    {
        $returnStr.='<p><input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$array[$i].'"/> '.$array[$i].'</p>';
    }
    return $returnStr;
}
```

Then just call it

```
<h3>Organisation?</h3>
<p><b>It was well organised</b></p>
<?php echo answers("org",array("Agree","Disagree"));?>
```

Comment: you mixed up the params order in the function call

Comment: So I did! Good catch!

Comment: @JamesHunt Sorry for the late reply but I will be using this code for another form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<?php $questions = array(
    'org' => 'It was well organized',
    'lib' => 'Adequate materials?',
); ?>
<h3>Organisation?</h3>
<?php foreach ($questions as $f => $question): ?>
    <p><b><?= $question; ?></b></p>
    <?php foreach (array('Disagree', 'Agree') as $answer): ?>
        <input type="radio" name="<?= $f ?>" value="<?= $answer ?>"> <?= $answer ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<h3>Organisation?</h3>

<?php
    $answers = array("Disagree","Agree");
    $first = ""; $second = "";
    foreach($answers as $answer) {
        $first .=  '<input type="radio" name="org" value="' . $answer . '">' . $answer;
        $second .= '<input type="radio" name="lib" value="' . $answer . '">' . $answer;
    }

    echo "<p><b>It was well organised</b></p><p>" . $first . "</p>";
    echo "<p><b>Adequate materials?</b></p><p>" . $second . "</p>";


?>
```

Comment: But user666 said these two questions were but a snippet, for your solution you would need to manually create a variable for every question. Plus it limits the answers to just Agree or Disagree so you would need a new loop for every collection of possible answers, rendering your solution of a single loop for faster processing a little redundant if multiple loops may be necessary anyway.